# How to run function on list with error propagation

Tags: haskell, monads

Help me please in following thing:
I have two functions:

```
eFAs :: [Ex] -> [AD] -> ReaderT E (StateT St (ErrorT String IO)) [(VN, TT)]

eFA :: (Ex, AD) -> ReaderT E (StateT St (ErrorT String IO)) (VN, TT)
```

Now, I would like to be use `eFA` in `eFAs`, in order to return list or Error (keep in your mind error propagation).

Exactly, I mean that `eFAs` apply `eFA` for each element of `zip Ex AD` (only intuition)  and return list of pairs (using `eFA`) or Error (in case of error from `eFA` or `eFAa`

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it would type check to just have

```
eFAs exs ads = mapM eFA (zip exs ads)
```

So you would quite literally be doing a pure `zip` of those lists, then just using the normal machinery of `mapM` to do the rest.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: There's also `zipWithM`. This will be especially nice if it's reasonable to uncurry the type of `eFA` -- and even if not, it can be uncurried at its use site.